# C++ variable naming

Tags: c++, variables, visual-c++, syntax, naming

The following C++ code compiles in Visual Studio:

```
void main() {
    int f() = 5;
std::cout << typeid(f()).name();    // int
}
```

and, for as long as I can see, it doesn't work with gcc or g++ in Linux (I tried compiling it in a Virtual Machine running Ubuntu and on a physical one running Mint, both with the updates to date).

But, the variable f() can't be use anywhere. The following code:

```
void main() {
    int f() = 5;
    cout << f();
}
```

gives this errors:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl f(void)" (?f@@YAHXZ) referenced in function _main
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

What I want to know is why it works, what is f(), and, if this is a valid naming, how can it be used.

### EDIT

It works with both Visual Studio 2013 and Visual C++ 2010.

#### PS: I didn't tried to define a function or declare a variable or anything. I heard of this behaviour, and I couldn't find an explanation why.

It seems that the debugger doesn't recognize f() as a variable (as it was expected);
Also, proof that it works :D under VS2013.
[image]

Comment: An identifier cannot contain punctuation.

Comment: `int f()` is interpreted as a declaration of a function taking no arguments and returning an `int`. You can't assign a value to that. And since it's not defined (only declared) the MSVC linker can't resolve it. I don't know why it compiles in the first place.

Comment: You should use `int main()` for starters.

Comment: Also important: which version of VS is it that lets you do this?

Comment: @juanchopanza I heard about this, and I just put it in an empty project to be sure it works.

Comment: This is a known issue in the 2013 compiler, it looks like there was a bug filed internally here at MSVC for it back in October.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 int f() = 5;
```

You stumbled upon the "most vexing parse".
What the compiler makes out of that (also according to the linker error you get) is a function declaration/pointer. Everything that can be parsed as a function declaration will be.
This code declares a function named f that takes no arguments and returns an int. My guess is Visual Studio assumes that this function is now at memory address 5.

What you probably want is to use f as a variable, so omit the parentheses:

```
int f = 5;
```

Comment: Yes, but it's *not* "most vexing parse". That's a specific ambiguity - there's nothing ambiguous here, it's just plain *wrong*. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: So it compiles because it thinks I declared a function, and when it tries to get to that function, it realise there is no function?

Comment: @tase92 that's exactly what happens.

Comment: Although it is not ambiguous for C++, it was for the OP. The reason behind the error appearing is the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

`int f() = 5;` is not valid syntax.

I assume you want something like this.

```
int f() { return 5; }

int main()
{
    std::cout << f();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because

```
     int f() = 5;
```

is not a variable.  To declare an integer variable in C++, you cannot include parenthesis.  As such, the correct code would be

```
    int f = 5;
```

So the total complete code would be

```
    void main() 
    {
       int f = 5;
       cout << f;
    }
```

Also generally 
        void main() 
is no longer used and it is

```
    int main()
    { 
       int f = 5;
       cout << f;
       return 0;
    }
```

instead.  It depends on the age of your compilier but this is generally the accepted way of doing things now.